# Ruby on Rails + PHP | How To Pair PHP AND Ruby On The Same Webserver?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to pair PHP and Ruby on Rails on the same server? Although I'd be using RoR More, I'd still like to have PHP, is this possible? And are there any major drawbacks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is definitely possible. You can enable / set up both mod_php and mod_passenger. It will depend on your OS how to do this. Basically, you need to enable both modules, then have separate virtual hosts: one for PHP and one for Ruby.

If you let me know your OS or more about what you want to achieve I can make this answer more detailed.

The drawback is increased memory usage, and possibly more complex security needs by enabling PHP. But it's not a huge drawback.

Comment: A dedicated Linux box running Apache could handle this I suppose then?

Comment: For sure, even a cloud server or VPS can handle it. It all depends on the memory requirements of each app. For ubuntu, you can `sudo a2enmod php` (if not already) and also `sudo a2enmod passenger`. It's probably better to get the latest passenger via ruby gems than via the apt repository.

Comment: Hi Ivanoats, could you please have a look here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13090988/running-rails-applications-with-passenger-alongside-php-applications

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely possible.

There are many ways to go about it. One way is to install both PHP and Passenger modules in Apache and route requests through Apache.

Another method, and the one I personally use to handle PHP and Rails on the same server, is to setup nginx in front of your PHP / Rails server mechanism of choice and have nginx rewrite requests.

Cookie (and sessions) can be shared between PHP and Rails to make the experience smooth for your users.